# Dialog box appear that only characters are allowed but after click ok on dialog box numeric also entered in text fields

Tags: java, swing

Numeric also enters in name text fields, this code is not working properly.  Please help me by example.

```
   Name_text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() { 

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
           if(e.getKeyChar()>='0'&& e.getKeyChar()<='9'|| e.getKeyChar()>=33&& e.getKeyChar()<=47|| e.getKeyChar()>=58&& e.getKeyChar()<=64 || e.getKeyChar()>=91&& e.getKeyChar()<=96 || e.getKeyChar()>=123&& e.getKeyChar()<=127 ){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter characters only");
        }
        }
           });
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

There are much better ways to accomplish what you want.

Check out [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Comment: its not sufficient,,,,,plz help with example

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. Read the tutorial, try out the sample, it's not hard to follow.

Comment: Please fix that stuck ',' key and type all the letters of words like 'please'.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted only shows a dialog complaining that numbers are not allowed (with an ugly check, what was wrong with the regex `[0-9]` ) but it does not remove the input.

Further, as stated in other answers there are built-in validation mechanisms or better ways then using a `KeyListener`:

- `JFormattedTextField` is the text field for validating user input. It requires a few tweaks to improve the usability (see for example [this blogpost](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/formatted-text-field-tips/))
- Use an `InputVerifier`. No link here as I am no fan of this mechanism. Just mentioning it for completeness
- Use a [`DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), which allows to suppress certain input, and will also work when using Drag-and-Drop or copy-paste which is not the case for your `KeyListener`

Examples can be found in the links.